# stepping_isProbablePrime(t) from Oka's Library (Prime number generation)

Tags: numbers, primes

I really need your help.  I'm trying to call the function found in Oka's library called stepping_isProbablePrime(t).  It allows me to call this function asynchronously.  The problem is I'm so new to Javascript I can't comprehend how I can call this function within a loop.

http://ats.oka.nu/titaniumcore/js/crypto/RSA.sample1.html
http://ats.oka.nu/titaniumcore/js/nonstructured/nonstructured.readme.txt

Those two links lead to an example of the prime number generation he's done, and the second link leads to the structure that handles the asychronous calls.  Also note that if you open the library to try and call this function yourself, the function is found within biginteger.init3.js.

http://ats.oka.nu/titaniumcore/js/crypto/readme.txt

Here's one more link just for a general overview of his library.  I really need your help guys, I've tried contacting the writer, and I've tried reddit.  As well as countless hours trying to grasp and implement this function by reading whatever I can find.